# Bidimentional Array

Tags: java, loops

Hi all my program consist of an 2 Dimension array,im reading 2 cordinates in a loop and triying to check if those cordinates in the array  are alredy been filled with a asterisc,if this is true y want to re-enicialize my array with the default value "-", and if there is not an asterisc in that specified position y want to fill it in with a asterisc,im not sure if im going for the correct aproach.

this is part of my code.
thanks all.

```
    String[][] matrix = new String[5][5];
    String asterisc = "*";
    String defaultValue = "_";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a, b;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {

            matrix[i][j] = defaultValue;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {

            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + "|");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    a = 0;
    b = 0;

    while (a >= 0 && b >= 0 && a < matrix.length && b <  matrix.length) {

        a = sc.nextInt();
        b = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {

                if (matrix[a][b].equals(asterisc)) {

                    matrix[i][j] = defaultValue;

                } else {

                    matrix[a][b] = asterisc;

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried verifying/testing your code? What specific issue are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

There are unfortunately many things wrong with your code.

Also you have not explained what your algorithm is trying to do.

In brief, to set all asterisks to defaults, you can do

```
 for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {

        if matrix[i][j].equals(asterisc){
           matrix[i][j]=defaultValue;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**But**
why are you using a while loop?

Why are you using a scanner?

Why are a and b initialised at zero, yet need to be greater than zero for the loop?

Are you really trying to re-initialise your whole array, every time the (a,b) item is asterisc?

Comment: Hi,what i want to imitate with my program are the pixels on a computer screen,y want to repeat my loop ultil one of the cordinates is negative if this happens y want to finish,A and B are te cordinates y want to read in the loop if this cordinate (A-B) is already containts a asterisc y want to re-initialise the array to default value if not y want to set the asterisc in the (A-B) position.

Comment: Hi Ricki, I am not sure I can help you further, because I don't understand your English -- Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not true.Suppose you have typed "6 6" in the terminal,then the variable a=6,and b=6,which is greater than the array length,and the program will throw a exception.I think the thing you may want to do can follow this code：

```
while(true){
    a = sc.nextInt();
    b = sc.nextInt();
    if(a<0||a>matrix.length||b<0||b>matrix.lenght)
        break;
}
```